# Why Doesn't Mercurial Make it Easy to Ignore Uncommitted Files on a Merge?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Am I not understanding something here? I've not committed these files. They shouldn't exist in a change-set anywhere. While I do appreciate Mercurial's efforts to preserve any work I've done that I might want to keep why isn't the sensible design choice on Mercurial's part:

a) Ignore them as per the general process where they effectively are if you remember to pull/update before committing changes in other files.

or

b) Ask user if s/he'd like them overwritten / if no, give directions on how to merge with the proper args that tell Mercurial to ignore files with uncommitted changes in them.

How did we get to:

c) Refuse to do anything forcing user to Google for some hack-ish solution to work around a popular version control system's complete inability to take into account that sometimes we forget to pull/update before commits and most of us (unfortunately) have a ton of config files we never want committed.

What is it I'm not getting here? Why is it all or nothing like this? And given that there's a reason for it, why is there no "duh" way to establish these files as off-limits in the first place? I'm getting semi-ranty here but I am legitimately trying to understand. What's the win here that  hasn't sunk in yet that makes such awkwardness necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about how you're using Mercurial, we can only make guesses as to what is happening.  Your main question seems to be why isn't there an easy way to make Mercurial ignore uncommitted changes, and secondly why are we forced to commit changes prior to a merge.

Answering the second question first, performing a merge between two changesets makes those changesets the parents of the new, merged changeset.  For this reason, you must not have pre-existing (uncommitted) changes in your working directory (it must be "clean").  If you tried to merge in another changeset to a "dirty" working directory, and then decided to undo that merge rather than commit it, Mercurial wouldn't know what state to put the working directory back to.  Why can't you tell Mercurial to ignore merging files that have changes in them?  Because Mercurial doesn't work on a per-file basis, it works on a "changeset" basis, where a single changeset holds the state of all tracked files at that moment in time (unlike something like Subversion, which makes it dangerously simple to mix-and-match file versions).

If your plan is to lose any of your local changes when you merge, you simply need to get rid of any local changes first, which you can do by performing a clean update, as per the Mercurial help: `hg update --clean .`

As for your first question, there is a very simple way to ignore things you don't want stored in a repository, and that's by using the `.hgignore` file to specify those files. You mention that most of you "have a ton of config files we never want committed", which is exactly what the `.hgignore` file is for.  Mercurial will ignore those files, and they will never be committed (unless you *explicitly* add them).  So if you had changed them, they would still be ignored by Mercurial, and everything would work marvelously.  A caveat to this is that if a file is already tracked by the repository, then it's too late to ignore it.

There are solutions if you decide you really need to merge prior to committing the changes you've made (the MQ and Shelve extensions spring to mind), but then you would still have the potential issue of merging back in the changes you've made onto the new working directory, meaning you would have two merges to perform rather than just one.

Your final question is "What is it I'm not getting here?".  While I don't wish to sound harsh, your question suggests that you're "not getting" how Mercurial should be configured and used.  You need to spend some time reading up on features such as `.hgignore`, and perhaps have a look around (even here on SO) for how other people are using Mercurial, and their workflows.  The [Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/) is a good place to look, and covers things like merging (Ch2), file ignoring (Ch7), and so on. It's a good read even for a seasoned Mercurial user.

I hope that's some help.

Comment: No, no, I was inviting criticism. It's just been a point of frustration to which I've seen many hacky/kludgey solutions when googling. Thx for the info. I'll look into ignore. But yes, I definitely am of the opinion version control should be a little more straightforward or at least have documentation that actually points you in the right direction.

Comment: Well as I mentioned, it is probably too late to set up an ignore file for your repository, unless you subsequently `hg forget` those files, which means they will no longer be tracked (tho' they'll still be in the history). And that Definitive Guide is certainly worth a read.

Comment: We basically clone a new repo on every version change so I should be able to add to that.